# Alternative for R package concaveman to create polygons

Tags: r, gis, polygon, raster

I have a script using the R package 'concaveman', but due to issues on the ubuntu platform that I need to run the code on I cannot install this package (it has taken me three days trying to solve it). So I am looking for an alternative.

I have a random set of points ranging from 3 to 1000s of points. I want to draw a convex hull/polygon around the outer most points (step after would be to rasterize). I have been trying to do it by converting the points to a raster, then use rastertopolygons, but in rare occasions points would be in the same raster cell resulting in only two unique points. Convaveman would make this into a linear polygon (which is what I want, without using concaveman). Here is the input data that would be problematic:

```
x <- structure(list(x = c(166.867, 166.867, 167.117, 166.8667), y = c(-20.6333, 
-20.633, -20.833, -20.6333)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is what I tried not (with the error I get):

```
SP_pt       <- SpatialPoints(x, proj4string=crs("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 `+towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs"))`
gridded(SP_pt) <- T
SP_pt_R     <- raster(SP_pt)
SP_poly     <- rasterToPolygons(SP_pt_R, dissolve = T)

suggested tolerance minimum: 0.333333 
Error in points2grid(points, tolerance, round) : 
  dimension 1 : coordinate intervals are not constant
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `chull` in base R:

```r
sp::Polygon(x[c(chull(x), chull(x)[1]), ])
#> An object of class "Polygon"
#> Slot "labpt":
#> [1] 166.95023 -20.69977
#> 
#> Slot "area":
#> [1] 6.75e-05
#> 
#> Slot "hole":
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> Slot "ringDir":
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> Slot "coords":
#>             x        y
#> [1,] 167.1170 -20.8330
#> [2,] 166.8667 -20.6333
#> [3,] 166.8670 -20.6330
#> [4,] 167.1170 -20.8330
```

Or if you want to use the `sf` package:

```r
sf::st_polygon(list(as.matrix(x[c(chull(x), chull(x)[1]),])))
#> POLYGON ((167.117 -20.833, 166.8667 -20.6333, 166.867 -20.633, 167.117 -20.833))
```

Comment: Thank you! Somehow I cannot transform the resulting polygon to sf.. any ideas?

Comment: I get the following error if I try: 
Error in UseMethod("st_cast") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_cast' applied to an object of class "c('Polygon', 'Line')"

Comment: @Shark167 why not just create the `st_polygon` directly if you want to use `sf` ? See my update

Comment: Good point, but then it still won't let me rasterize:
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘rasterize’ for signature ‘"XY", "RasterLayer"’
In addition: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `individualCount`.

Comment: EDIT: would actually like to rasterize it using 'fasterize', but this gives me the following message: Error in fasterize(y, WorldGrd, field = NULL) : 
  Could not convert using R function: as.data.frame.

Comment: Got it! Fasterize needs sf input, so transformed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dismo::convHull` and then use `predict` or `rasterize`

```
library(dismo)
xy <- cbind(x=c(1,1,2,2), y=c(3,2,1,2))
# must be matrix or data.frame, not a tbl
ch <- convHull(xy)
plot(ch)

# predict
r <- raster(xmn=0, xmx=5, ymn=0, ymx=5, res=.25)
p <- predict(ch, r)

# Or rasterize
sp <- polygons(ch)
x <- rasterize(sp, r)
```

For faster rasterization you can use `terra`

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(sp)
rr <- rast(r)
y <- rasterize(v, rr)
```

To cast `sp` to sf

```
sf <- as(sp, "sf")
```